# Is it okay to write a post on a main site as a result of chatroom jokes, or is that considered abusive?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

The situation:

- A post appeared on one of the SE sites in all-caps shouting [HOW DO I TURN OFF CAPS LOCK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539471/how-do-i-turn-off-caps-lock).
- Chat users generally try to help salvage such shouting posts on the SE network, whenever they are reported. I too, went to take a look and attempt to salvage it.
- It was a self-answered post by a 4K+ user and after a few minutes, a note appeared on the post saying that *it is meant to be a canonical post for closing all shouting posts as duplicates. It was posted as on the advice of a moderator. [A link to the chat room conversation was provided in the question by the author.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18239652#18239652)*
- After some time, the post was deleted, then undeleted, [as the OP was trying to get a badge with assistance from the chat room users,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18240414#18240414) and now it is finally deleted.
- All these events kept bumping the post till it was finally removed by the author.

My questions:

- Is it considered a abuse of the system if a users post like this knowingly on a main site?
- Should such posts be flagged, or should I just let it be, because moderators were part of the joke as well?

Thoughts?

Comment: You mean like this [staged April fools joke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression)? (a work of the C++ lounge) Who cares where it comes from? If the question is legit by itself, it's legit. That said, the example you've given sounds like it was not of the best quality. :)

Comment: @Mysticial: Yes, this question wasn't good quality. The entire question was in UPPERCASE and the answer had a image of the caps-lock keys, saying turn off the caps lock by pressing that key or type `xkbset nullify lock` in lowercase by pressing shift key. That post was posted for deletion, that is why I am confused if it was an abuse. If it had been written to be kept on the site, then it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Abuse! Posting crap is posting crap, "a moderator told me so" is not an excuse.

In this case, the answer contained a picture of a caps lock key which is kinda inappropriate and condescending.

Gaming badges is always bad.

Encouraging bad behavior via chat should be punished.

Comment: "Chat rooms encouraging bad behavior should be shut down." - then you'd have to shut down the entire chat.[meta.]stack{overflow|exchange}.com eventually.

Comment: @Jan Yeah that works better for rooms only for encouraging bad behavior, edited.